# Android background images blurring for mobile website?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a mobile site and have noticed that on android all the background images are rendering very poorly, they all seem to be quite blurred? Has anyone come across this problem? The image im using is 131 x 32px in png 24 format and the file size is 5.37kb. Im using the latest version of android 3.2.2. I have read an article online where someone was having the same problem but their problem was due to a large canvas size which isnt the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote an article about this if you want a [full explanation](http://programming-perils.com/308/why-background-images-look-blurry-on-mobile-devices/).

Long story short, use a larger image (393 x 96 pixels) and then use *background-size* to shrink it:

```
background-size: 131px 32px;
```